# How to prevent very small numbers from being converted to scientific notation?

Tags: javascript

I have to use very small numbers:

```
var x = 0.00000006;
```

When I run *console.log(x)*, it shows:

```
6e-8
```

I don't want it to show **6e-8** , I want it to show **0.00000006**.

Later I need to plot it on a graph, so I can't convert it to a string.
How to keep it a small number without converting it to a string or scientific notation?

Comment: Why not convert it to a string when you need to `console.log` it (or otherwise display it as a string) and use it as a number otherwise?

Comment: I have to pass it to an external charting library that takes numbers

Comment: So? Pass the number to the library, and if you need a string as well, convert it to a string and use it

Comment: A number by itself doesn't contain any formatting information. You can't print "0.00000006" without converting to a string. And, as the other commenter said, you don't have to change the original value if you print it as a string in the console.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to "fixed" shape and get it to look like you want. Example would be:

```
var number = 6e-8; //this is your number
number = number.toFixed(8) //but since you won't always know how many decimal points you have you can use something like
number = number.toFixed(number.toString().split('-')[1]); //where you split your number, see how many decimals it has and pass that number to .toFixed method
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be more correct,
only the last part after the e- notation is not the enough to be always the number you need to provide in toFixed

```
// containing Scientific Notation to a readable number string
export const convertScientificNotationNumber = (value) => {
    const decimalsPart = value?.toString()?.split('.')?.[1] || '';
    const eDecimals = Number(decimalsPart?.split('e-')?.[1]) || 0;
    const countOfDecimals = decimalsPart.length + eDecimals;
    return Number(value).toFixed(countOfDecimals);
    //0.4210854715202004e-14).toFixed(30)
};
```